# Streaming error: InternetSetStatusCallback is called again before the previous call exited

Tags: c++, http, winapi, https

I'm using InternetSetStatusCallback for streaming data:

```
CallbackPointer = InternetSetStatusCallback(SessionHandle,
    (INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK)CallBack);
```

Sometimes the below CallBack function is called again before it exits despite the streamed data is sent in every 250ms, so the program should have enough time to process the data.

```
bool InsideFunc = false;

VOID CALLBACK
CallBack(
__in HINTERNET hInternet,
__in DWORD_PTR dwContext,
__in DWORD dwInternetStatus,
__in_bcount(dwStatusInformationLength) LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
__in DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
)
{
    if (InsideFunc)
    {
            // should not happen
    }
    InsideFunc = true;

    cOandaFeed* oandaFeed = (cOandaFeed*)dwContext;
    ASSERTRETURN(oandaFeed);

    ASSERT(dwContext);

    switch (dwInternetStatus) {
    case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED:
        oandaFeed->StatusHandle = lpvStatusInformation;
        break;
    case INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE:
        if (oandaFeed->State == cOandaFeed::OPENING)
            oandaFeed->StartFeeding();
        break;
    case INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED:
        if (oandaFeed->State == cOandaFeed::FEEDING) {
            oandaFeed->ReadFile(); // this is where I call InternetReadFileEx
            oandaFeed->CollectAndForwardChunks();
        }
        break;
    case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING:
        oandaFeed->SetState(cOandaFeed::IDLE);
        break;
    case INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE:
        break;
    }

    InsideFunc = false;
}
```

So the program correctly initializes and than gets the INTERNET_STATUS_RECEIVING_RESPONSE and INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED status responses among others. So far so good. But the next iteration goes wrong, InternetReadFileEx called twice and get error messages, one for pending IO, and one for internal error by InternetReadFileEx. The next round is good again and then the errors.

I did the "bool insideFunc" trick to see if what I suspect is happening and yes, sometimes "calling" is true before setting is, so sometimes it is called before it even ends. I only want to read my message on INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED but sometimes the CallBack() gets called again before it finishes and InternetReadFileEx happens with a bad timing, resulting it returning error codes 997 and 12004.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try changing your callback code to queue up an asynchronous call to `oandaFeed->ReadFile()` and `oandaFeed->CollectAndForwardChunks()` (and maybe `oandaFeed->StartFeeding()` too) so the callback can exit before they are executed, rather than executing them inside the callback itself. For that matter, why are you using your callback to drive your streaming logic? It is a status mechanism, not a business logic runner. Why can't you simply call `InternetReadFile/Ex()` in a loop from the same code that initiates the request to begin with?

Comment: Call InternetQueryDataAvailable result in INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED so you then call InternetReadFileEx  to read the data? Can you describe your logic of what you are doing or show a sample that can reproduce this issue? And @RemyLebeau is right, it is not best practice to put InternetReadFile operation in the callback.

Comment: And check the InternetReadFile return value before next call.  Use GetLastError function to check functions execute state. More reference "[Handling Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/appendix-c-handling-errors)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this easily. The problem was that I kept my ReadFile() call in the INTERNET_STATUS_RESPONSE_RECEIVED case in the switch. It caused trouble because that status is sent via the callback **while inside the call for the InternetReadFileEx()**, inside my ReadFile(), causing a recursive call to the ReadFile() again.

So the first ReadFile() call resulted in the 997: ERROR_IO_PENDING, while the second call (caused but recursion) resulted in the 12004: internal error.

**Solution:** After I've moved my ReadFile() to the INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE case in the switch, I only get the ERROR_IO_PENDING, since we don't get a CallBack inside ReadFile(), with this status. We get this status asynchronously, long after InternetReadFileEx() has returned. ERROR_IO_PENDING is normal:

> Note  The GetLastError code ERROR_IO_PENDING is not a failure; it designates the read operation is pending completion asynchronously.

quoted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile

Streaming works by

1. Calling an InternetReadFileEx()
2. it returns an IO pending
3. when it has new data (price), it just sends it async via INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE.
4. If it doesn't have any data (no price change) for a few seconds, it just sends a heartbeat via INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE to avoid timeout.
5. I call InternetReadFileEx() immediately again, after I received the data (see #1)

This is how streaming works at Oanda but I guess it's common practice?

Thank you everyone for the replies.